# DocuSign API - Create Envelope but Not Send and Get Link to send via CRM/SMS

Tags: docusignapi

I'm successfully creating and sending envelopes via the DocuSign API which is working well. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to do the following:

1. create the envelope like I presently do
2. not have it send by DocuSign but rather capture the URL/link that would normally be sent to the recipient
3. send out an email from our CRM system or possibly via SMS with the link instead

My request looks like this at present:

```
    {
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "API Signature Request",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "bob.smith@docusign.com",
            "name": "Bob Smith",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
        }]
    }
}
```

Not sure what changes I would need to make here? I still want the status as "sent" in DocuSign but don't want DocuSign to send the email like they do automatically as we will be sending the link immediately after the request has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two ways to request signatures:

1. Embedded Signing - inside your app, no email. You get a URL used to embed.
2. Remote Signing - DocuSign sends an email to recipients on your behalf. You can still make this email look and feel customized using branding.

DocuSign highly recommend that if you wish emails to be sent, they are sent using #2 above. This ensures highest security and prevent phishing attacks and other issues.

If you still insist, you can get a URL using #1 above (embedded signing). However, that URL is only good for a few minutes (again, security) and would not work unless you refresh it.
To solve this problem (again, only if you insist) you can set up a URL that goes to your web-server and generates the other URL on the fly from DocuSign and then redirects the user. It would ensure that your URL works all the time and does not expire.
But, like I said three times already, we really recommend you don't do that.